# what does "______, thy name is ______" mean?

Tags: idioms

No only can I not get what the following sentence means, I fail to understand the concept of the bold part, as well.

> **Frailty**, thy name is **woman**

**"______, thy name is ______"**

Answer (score 13):

> Frailty, thy name is woman

The meaning of the sentence is "women *embody* frailty to the full extent" or

> The quality called "frailty" is most closely expressed by the object called "woman".

or, even:

> Women are so frail that the words "frailty" and "woman" are equal in meaning.

That is, women are considered to be more delicate, more frail than men. The author of the sentence tries to express it in "high language", to add emphasis.

Other examples of the same structure:

> Treachery thy name is government bureaucrat! ([source](http://books.google.ru/books?id=YQI3nsIRdDIC&lpg=PA49&dq=%22treachery%2C%20thy%20name%20is%22&hl=ru&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=%22treachery,%20thy%20name%20is%22&f=false))

It turns out there's a Wikipedia page about this structure: **"[Thy name is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thy_name_is)".**

Comment: Also same as saying "women are the *personification* of frailty"

Answer (score 0):

"Frailty, thy name is woman" - with these words Hamlet in Shakespeare's play complains that his mother has married again shortly after his father's death.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/142800.html
Hamlet, act 1, scene 2.

Comment: But that doesn't explain the meaning or structure of the sentence, does it? If someone asks what "here's looking at you, kid" means, I can list Bogey's movies and say he said it when drinking, but it doesn't answer what it means...

Comment: The poster says that he doesn't understand the meaning. I think when one reads Hamlet, act 1, scene 2 the meaning should become clear.

Comment: Maybe the OP can get insight from reading a suitable translation of Hamlet to their mother tongue (or the Klingon original)